# mass renaming of files not working

Tags: bash, rename

Quite a few similar question are being asked. The error is probably staring at me in the face, but I just can't see it...

```
#!/bin/bash
declare -a files
shopt -s nullglob       
files=(*)
count=36   # offset

for oldfilename in "${files[@]}"; do
    (( count++ ))
#   newfilename=$(echo "$oldfilename" | sed -e "s/^[1-9][0-9]?\.jpg/Scount\.png/")
#   newfilename=${oldfilename/[1-9][0-9]?/Scount}
#   newfilename=${oldfilename/[1-9][0-9]?/"Scount"}
    newfilename=${oldfilename//[1-9][0-9]?/Scount}
    echo mv -fv /path1/to/"${oldfilename}" /path2/to/"${newfilename}"
done
exit 0
```

I have tried commented lines.
I don't know the difference between `/` and `//` in `newfilename=${oldfilename/[1-9][0-9]?/"Scount"}`.   o_0 ?

***EDIT:***
Files represented by `$oldfilename` have the form `1.jpg` to `99.jpg`. Output files `$newfilename` are expected to have the form 37.png to 135.png (at least as far as the `sed` invocation goes).
Somehow files are not renamed and the dot in `.jpg` disappears. 
Why does this not work ?

Comment: Sample of input filenames and to what you expect them to be transformed please

Comment: Shouldn't that be `$count` instead of `Scount`? And, if so, you probably rather want `$(printf "%02d" $count)` to keep file names length constant (i.e. keep leading zeroes).

Comment: Is that an `S` in stead of a `$` where you attempt to define `newfilename`?

Comment: Can you clarify what is happening? ("not working" is pretty vague.)  Also, please clarify what you *want* to happen.  It looks like you want to rename `1.jpg` → `37.jpg`, `2.jpg` → `38.jpg`, etc.  But what if you already have a file named `37.jpg` or `38.jpg`?  Does the `sed` version work when you replace `Scount` with `$count`?  (And do you *really* want to rename `*.jpg` files to `*.png`?)

Comment: Sorry to all for lacking in details. Somehow they're evident to me but understandably not to others. Here goes... @roaima : input file name have the form 1.jpg to 99.jpg. Output file names have the form 37.png to 135.png.  @perterph: Thanks. It definitely should be `$count` instead of my nonsensical `Scount`. Leading zeroes for filenames starting with one or two digit numerals are already taken care of in the routine in which this snippet is inserted.

Comment: @Scott: yes, on all counts. Thanks for your heads-up on my lacking post.

Comment: Please give _specific_ examples of the source files and the transformed ones. What are the rules for getting from one to the other? Is it simply "add 36"? If so please say so.

Comment: @roaima: I thought my response (comment) and edit  (post) were clear. All file names' leading numerals are to be incremented by 36. Additionally the file suffix goes from .jpg to .png.

Comment: Well, that's not exactly what the code is written to do. (1) It doesn't simply add 36, unless you guarantee that all 99 files are present. If, for example, `2.jpg` and `3.jpg` are missing, it will rename `1.jpg` → `37.ext` and `4.jpg` → `38.ext`. (2) Unless you're using some other shell option that you're not showing (and that I don't know about), the code will process the files in the wrong order. `*` sorts lexicographically, not numerically, so it puts `10`…`19` before `2`, `20`…`29` before `3`, …, just as "ha", "he", "hi" and "ho" sort before "i". You may need to say `files=(?.jpg ??.jpg)`.

Comment: @G-Man: correct. The snippet is just that for which my bad eyes could not see the error last night. In reality I check indirectly for consistency in terms of file availibility by capturing the leading numerals of the existing files and doing `+36` arythmetics on it before injecting the result in the new filename. So I don't have a file order or a missing file problem at all. All in all my post is pretty badly worded. I'd consider erasing it, if it weren' t for yr accepted answer. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I guess from your (commented out) `sed` command that you want
to match and replace a regular expression: `[1-9][0-9]?`, meaning

- a non-zero digit (`[1-9]`), followed by
- zero or one digit(s) (`[0-9]?`)

which is a fairly common regex for an integer between 1 and 99 (with no leading zero). 
However, `${parameter/pattern/string}`
doesn't use regexs, it uses pathname expansion patterns (a.k.a. wildcards). 
So `[1-9][0-9]?` means

- a non-zero digit (`[1-9]`), followed by
- a digit (`[0-9]`), followed by
- any character (`?`)

Still, it should have worked for the two-digit filenames,
although it would consume the `.` and rename `10.jpg` to `46jpg`
(without `.`).

---

Regarding the other part of your question,
`//` replaces all occurrences of the *pattern*,
while `/` replaces only the first.  For example,

```
$ i=cataract
$ echo "${i/a/X}"
cXtaract
$ echo "${i//a/X}"
cXtXrXct
```

Answer (score 1):

If you have the Perl `rename` (sometimes called `prename`) you can do this:

```
rename -v 's!(\d+)(.*)\.jpg$!sprintf "%d%s.png", $1+36, $2!e' *.jpg
```

This takes each filename, splits off the leading digits, the rest of the filename component, and the trailing `.jpg`. It then adds 36 to the numeric part, adds on the remainder of the original filename, and replaces the suffix with `.png`.

Use `rename -n ...` to see what would happen with it changing anything, or remove the `-v` to have it run silently.