# move middle part of filename to front

Tags: shell, rename

I have files named in the style `02.04.11 DJ Kilbot.mp3` (for several dates) and I want to reformat the name in this manner: `DJ Kilbot 2011-02-04.mp3`. In other words, the current format is `MM.DD.YY DJ-NAME.mp3` and I want to change it to `DJ-NAME YYYY-MM-DD.mp3`. What's the easiest way to do this, for several year's worth of files?

Comment: Do you have the perl rename ala http://unix.stackexchange.com/a/254066/117549 ?

Comment: `$ rename --version \ rename from util-linux 2.25.2` on cygwin, will see if it's available in packages.

Comment: @JeffSchaller OK, I installed it from here: https://github.com/mengbo/install/blob/master/cygwin/prename

Comment: I tend to use editable dired mode in emacs and define a macro and call it multiple times.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`cd` to the directory then run the following (using `perl-rename`). This is a "dry-run" first.

```
rename -n 's/^([0-9]{2})\.([0-9]{2})\.([0-9]{2}) (.*)\.mp3$/$4 20$3-$1-$2.mp3/' *
02.04.11 DJ Kilbot.mp3 -> DJ Kilbot 2011-02-04.mp3
```

If you are happy with the output, then run it for real.

```
rename 's/^([0-9]{2})\.([0-9]{2})\.([0-9]{2}) (.*)\.mp3$/$4 20$3-$1-$2.mp3/' *
```

#### Explanation

- `rename -n`: run a test "dry-run".
- `'s/FOO/BAR/'` substitute the regex `FOO` and replace with `BAR`.
- `^([0-9]{2})\.([0-9]{2})\.([0-9]{2}) (.*)\.mp3$`: regex to capture. Match the start of the string `^`, then three lots of `[0-9]{2}` (i.e. two consecutive numbers) separated by a dot (`\.` when escaped). Then a space and `(.*)\.mp3$`. Parens `()` capture the contents for use in the replacement.
- `$4 20$3-$1-$2.mp3`: replace with the DJ name the fourth capturing group (`$4`), or `(.*)` above, then the rest of the string as specified (i.e. the third, first and second groups).
- `*`: act on all files in the directory.

#### Simplify

This regex has a bit of error checking built in. If you are sure that all files are named consistently, you can simplify it slightly to the following.

```
rename 's/^(..)\.(..)\.(..) (.*)\.mp3$/$4 20$3-$1-$2.mp3/' *
```

Comment: You are welcome. Perl-`rename` is such a great tool!

Answer (score 3):

Without `rename`:

```
for file in *.mp3
do
  no_extension=${file%.mp3}
  the_date=$(echo "${no_extension}" | cut -d ' ' -f 1)
  year=20${the_date:6}
  month=${the_date:0:2}
  day=${the_date:3:2}
  date_part=${year}-${month}-${day}
  dj_part=$(echo "${no_extension}" | cut -d ' ' -f 2-)
  new_file="${dj_part} ${date_part}.mp3"
  mv "${file}" "${new_file}"
done
```

Explanation:

- `for file in *.mp3` loops through every file in the current directory that ends with the `.mp3` extension
- `${file%.mp3}` strips the `.mp3` extension from the end of the file using [bash string manipulation](http://www.tldp.org/LDP/LG/issue18/bash.html)
- `$(echo ${no_extension} | cut -d ' ' -f 2-)` extracts the date part of the file name by using the `cut` utility, which can parse character-delimited strings
- then we change the format of the date by extracting the substrings
- `"${dj_part} ${date_part}.mp3"` is just string concatenation of the parts we've built
- `mv "${file}" "${new_file}"` renames the file

Comment: Excellent answer.  I would just recommend using `printf %s` in place of `echo`, and quoting the variable `no_extension` when you use it.

Answer (score 0):

Assume that the files are named strictly that way.

```
for file in "*.mp3";do 
  date="${file:0:8}" #get the date in the filename. 
  dj="${file%.mp3}" #strip the extension off the filename. 
  dj="${dj:8}" # get dj name.
  mv -nv $file "$dj $date.mp3" # -n don't overwrite files. 
done
```

Comment: This is nice but it doesn't change the date format : /

Answer (score 0):

[pyRenamer](https://github.com/SteveRyherd/pyRenamer) has a GUI and allows for automatic preview.
Put this into the Original file name pattern field:

```
{#}.{#}.{#} {X}.mp3
```

And this into the Renamed file name patter:

```
{4} {3}-{1}-{2}.mp3
```

Only downside is that it sorts in "Windows" mode (1, 10, 11, 2, 3, 4 ...).